# Non annotated methos as nullable by default

Tags: intellij-idea, nullable, non-nullable, nullaway

Is it possible to configure the IntelliJ or maybe the [NullAway](https://github.com/uber/NullAway) to consider non annotated method as Nullable by default?

e.g. The following method:

`context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);`

The `getResources` is not annotated as nullable or non-null. I think it will be interesting to receive a warning "Maybe it will be null" in those cases, but neither the IntelliJ or the NullAway are telling me that it can be a possible NPE.

Comment: It's not particularly interesing in practice because you will have tens of thousands of such warnings and you won't be able to find the really problematic places.